# Getting error when trying to connect to metamask, although the metamask extension pops up

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ethers.js, hardhat

> could not coalesce error (error={ "code": -32002, "payload": { "method": "eth_requestAccounts", "params": [  ] } }, code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, version=6.6.1)
> at makeError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:84341:15)
> at BrowserProvider.getRpcError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80178:37)
> at BrowserProvider.getRpcError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:77869:18)
> at Bro

i am getting the error above when trying to connect to metamask, although the metamask extension pops up

this is my code snippet below

```js
    try {
        if(!window.ethereum) return console.log("install MetaMask")
        console.log("two...")

        const accts = await window.ethereum.request({
             method: "eth_requestAccounts"
        })
        console.log("two2...")
        setAcct(accts[0])
        const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        const contract = contractFetcher(signer) 

        const allHoldersID =  await contract.getUserId()
        const userAcctBal = await contract.balanceOf(accts[0])
        setUserID(allHoldersID)
        setAcctBalance(userAcctBal.toNumber())
        console.log(allHoldersID)
     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
```

i am new to this so i have not tried anything useful

Answer (score 0):

const signer = **await** provider.getSigner()

but I think it's not the only issue... maybe